# How to make a HTML Form Button place a Dropdown form list on the screen, which the user can input text to

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to make it so that I can have a HTML form which I can have a button within, which when the user of the website clicks that button, a <select> list appears for them to use, and then can input some text alongside that, which can work multiple times? (EDIT By this I mean I would like the whole process of selecting a day and inputting text to be able to be run multiple times, by clicking the button)

My code so far has a button and the dropdown to select from, but i'm not sure how to combine them to work together multiple times.

```html
            <br><label for='odays'> Open Days: </label><br>

            <input type='button' onclick='' value='Add Day'><br>

            <select id='odays'name='odays'>
                <option value='monday'> Monday </option>
                <option value='tuesday'> Tuesday </option>
                <option value='wednesday'> Wednesday </option>
                <option value='thursday'> Thursday </option>
                <option value='friday'> Friday </option>
                <option value='saturday'> Saturday </option>
                <option value='sunday'> Sunday </option>  
            </select>
```

This is my code so far

EDIT:
To clarify, this is what my intended end result is:
[End Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIUDl.png) My hope is that I can make it so that when the user clicks the 'Add Day' button, it creates another row below, for them to select a day and write into the text input. If it helps the context of this is that it is for a businesses opening hours.
It would also be appreciated if answers could be kept as simple as possible, as I am very new to HTML and JS

Comment: What is the desired result? user click on button, select box would appear and then what?

Comment: What is meant by '...can input some text alongside that, which can work multiple times?'

Comment: Well my plan is to have it so the selection box appears, the user can input text relevant to the form, and then they can do that however many times necessary (using the button, selecting a day, and inputting the text) and then to submit the form

Comment: Are you storing the data from the input and select somewhere maybe on click of a submit button?

Comment: A form submission loads a page by default. You should probably be using AJAX or fetch(). To toggle the visibility of an element, use the CSS rule {display:none;} or {display:block}. You can also consider using the CSS property visibility.

Comment: I do plan on making the data be stored into a database when the user fills in the form and submits it, but I didn't think that really mattered for my question

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
document.querySelector('#newEvent').addEventListener('click', function() { // when "add day" clicked:
  let chosenDay = odays.selectedOptions[0].value; // take the selected option from select box
  document.querySelector('#newNote legend').textContent += ' '+chosenDay; // Here i use it as title but you can do what you want
  document.querySelector('#newNote input').removeAttribute('disabled');  // since we disabled it initialy
  document.querySelector('#newNote').removeAttribute('style'); // show input ready for note
});
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>My Calendar</legend>
    <label for='odays'> Open Days: </label>
    <input type='button' id="newEvent" value='Add Day'><br>
    <select id='odays'name='odays'>
      <option value='monday'> Monday </option>
      <option value='tuesday'> Tuesday </option>
      <option value='wednesday'> Wednesday </option>
      <option value='thursday'> Thursday </option>
      <option value='friday'> Friday </option>
      <option value='saturday'> Saturday </option>
      <option value='sunday'> Sunday </option>  
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="newNote" style="display: none;">
    <legend>Note For</legend>
    <input type="text" placeholder="add some text" disabled>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a prompt box

```js
let daysPlan = "";

function updateMyday() {
  var selectBox = document.getElementById("odays");
  var div = document.getElementById("daysUp");
  //var selectOption = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex];
  var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;

  event = window.prompt("what's up that day ?");

  // to show on the page somewhere 
  var newDay = document.createElement("div");
  newDay.textContent = selectedValue + " : " + event;
  div.appendChild(newDay);
  // end show 

  // store it , a variable, a localstorge, else ?
  daysPlan += selectedValue + " : " + event + "\n"
  console.log(daysPlan) // to use and send once submitting 
}
```

```css
#odays {
  display: none;/* not sure i understood that part*/
}

form {
  float: left;
}

#daysUp {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<form><label for='odays'> Open Days: </label><br>

  <input type='button' onclick='let e =document.getElementById("odays"); e.style.display="block";' value='Add Day'><br>

  <select id='odays' name='odays' onchange="updateMyday()">
    <option>Choose a day </option>
    <option value='monday   '> Monday </option>
    <option value='tuesday  '> Tuesday </option>
    <option value='wednesday'> Wednesday </option>
    <option value='thursday '> Thursday </option>
    <option value='friday   '> Friday </option>
    <option value='saturday '> Saturday </option>
    <option value='sunday   '> Sunday </option>
  </select>
</form>
<div id="daysUp">
</div>
```